# Send Email with PHP Code

Tags: php, html, email

I'm trying to send an email in PHP that is written with CKEditor, or HTML. When the email is sent the HTML code appears in the email, I know it but the Headers already tried putting immense and none works.

Below is my code to send the email.

```
function mail_users($titulo, $conteudo){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `Email`, `Nome` FROM `utilizadores` WHERE `Newsletter` = 'Ativada'");
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false){
 $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
email($row['Email'], $titulo, "Olá " . $row['Nome'] . ",\n\n" .  $conteudo, $header);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this way..

- Move the header outside of the while loop.
- You are doing a mistake in concatenation.
- Function should be `mail()` instead of `email()` [*Unless you have written a wrapper for the same*]

---

#### The right way....

```
function mail_users($titulo, $conteudo){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `Email`, `Nome` FROM `utilizadores` WHERE `Newsletter` = 'Ativada'");
    
    $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false){
        
        mail($row['Email'], $titulo, "Olá " . $row['Nome'] . ",\n\n" .  $conteudo, $header);
    }
}
```

Comment: The function should be `mail` why are using `email()`  ? Did you make that change ?

Comment: i change this to `mail($row['Email'], $titulo, "Olá " . $row['Nome'] . ",\n\n" .  $conteudo, $headers);` but doesn't work..

Comment: @LuisMiguelGT, So the `mail()` was the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this  i think you just have to make header blank each time it enter into the loop.

and check

@mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);

the last line has all the values accordingly .

```
function mail_users($titulo, $conteudo){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `Email`, `Nome` FROM `utilizadores` WHERE `Newsletter` ='Ativada'");
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false){
$header='';
 $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
@mail($row['Email'], $titulo, "Olá" . $row['Nome'] . ",\n\n" .  $conteudo, $header);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function mail_users($titulo, $conteudo)
{
    $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "From: xyz@yourdomain.com";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `Email`, `Nome` FROM `utilizadores` WHERE `Newsletter` = 'Ativada'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {

         mail($row['Email'], $titulo, "Olá " . $row['Nome'] . ",\n\n" .  $conteudo, $header);
    }
}
```