# copy email address from table and paste them in a text field , seperated by commas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email

I have trying to create a mass mailer script.
I have managed for the script.

I have emails in the db , I want to select all the emails from the table and paste them in the text field on the form separated by commas,

```
select email from table ;
```

it displays a lot of emails , I want to copy the captured emails in the text field  separated by commas, i.e.

email,email2,email4,email2

the script will look the email in this field one by one and keep on sending the emails.

thanks for the guidance.

---

below is what I have done so  far .

```
<?php
$includes[title]="Mail List";
include('config.php');

$sql = $Db1->query("select group_concat(email) as email from user");
$temp=$Db1->fetch_array($sql);
$thismemberinfo['emails']=$temp[email];
echo "$thismemberinfo[emails]";

?>


<form name="form1" method="post" action="Send-Out-Mass-Email-PHP-script.php">
  <div align="center">
    <p class="style2"> Email Massal Form </p>
    <table width="40%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="37%" valign="top" class="style1">To </td>
        <td width="4%" valign="top" class="style1">:</td>
        <td width="59%" valign="top" class="style1"><label>
         <input name="email_list" type="text" id="email_list" size="25" value= $thismemberinfo[emails]>
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="style1"> Subject </td>
```

Emails are displayed in the commas separated format now,, But I am having troubles in pasting them in the text field.

Comment: I have no idea bro , how to achieve this task. that's y I have asked

Comment: If what you want to do is to send an Email to each address from DB, you're going about it all wrong.

Comment: I have a mass mailer with my website but it long working -- I have have the new code and works fine with me ....the might might not be upto the mark , but for my needs it should be enough ..

Comment: Or may be some suggestion from you for a mass mailer script , that I can use to send emails

Comment: This is one way http://stackoverflow.com/q/23196375/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/23828913/ you can base yourself on those.

Comment: Initially I wanted to display emails , in commas sepeareted formats, both the answers are same. I tried to accept both, to give credits to both ... but I guess this does not work

Comment: for me both are accepted

Comment: OK, and you're welcome. So I take it that it's running well then; I was just curious as to where you were having difficulties with.

Comment: @Fred-ii- .. just FYI , I am following this tutorial for sendind emails . and it works fine for me .. ---http://tutorial.world.edu/web-development/php-script/how-to-send-out-mass-emails-php-script/ ----------- Thanks All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, If you want all the emails separated by commas, you can do that with your MySQL query:

```
select group_concat(email) as emails from table ;
```

Comment: how to paste them in text field ?? I am confused in this ??

Comment: If you don't know how to "paste" the MySQL result into a textarea element, I really advice you to take a look at the W3Schools tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp. Especially this section http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_concat()` to do what you want:

```
select group_concat(email)
from table;
```

Note that there is a maximum size, which may not be sufficient if you have lots of email addresses.

By default, the maximum length is 1024.  You can reset the system variable `group_concat_max_len` to be larger, if you need.  The documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).

Comment: email count on my db increases daily..  .. once I extract the email .. how to paste them in the text field separated by commas ??

Comment: @Neha . . . That is not really a database question.  You should post the php code that you are using for the application.  You are probably better off looping through the result set in php and adding the emails one at a time.